# Tracking requests on a CDN file

Tags: php, javascript, css, cdn

I have spoken to a well known hosting company about tracking requests to a CDN file, they do not offer this.

What i want to do is allow the user to upload a CSS file/pure CSS, take this file or raw CSS and put it into the CDN, i then will give the user a unique link to their file, so they can do something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myCDN.com/uniquelink.css">` and for the file to be outputted as valid CSS. This is relatively simple, but i need to track how many requests are made to the file for charging purposes. How can i do this without getting them to go through a PHP script first (which defeats the object of giving them a speedy CDN link)?

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you rule out intermediate scripts that you control then I believe your only option is using normal stats that read the server logs. Meaning that you (or someone here might know of one) need to find a CDN provider that *does* support tracking (or web stats that you can access).

Answer (score 1):

I'm gunna have to agree with Blair McMillan, your best bet is to find a CDN that'll let you check access logs.

Though if that's really not an option, something you could try is CSS's @import feature.  At the top of your CSS, add `@import url("http://host.example.com/path-to-tracking-script.php?id=383");`  And that *should* trigger a request to your tracking script.  (You'll obviously not be able to get the HTTP REFERER if you're after that. [edit: since it'll always be your CSS file, not the page that loaded the css file])  Though I'm not aware of what kind of affect that might have on load performance, but it might be worth testing if you don't want to change CDNs.

Comment: This is a great idea, could i not also append an image call back to my server to a PHP endpoint with their user id embedded? Ie. .api {background:url('http://myAPi.com?uid=12345')}

Comment: You'd have to make sure they had an element on the page that made use of that rule.  If they don't, the image won't get downloaded. (At least with Firefox it won't.)  Something that crossed my mind is you could set a very generic rule and then override it back with whatever the user provided.  Say at the top on the body element, but I'm not sure if you can guarantee that won't affect their page styling.  (Nor can we necessarily guarantee that the image will be downloaded if the rule is immediately overridden.  All that behavior is very much up to the browser.)

Answer (score 0):

instead of giving the real link to the user, create a page on your server that logs the request and then redirects to the real link.

An example:

user loads a css file to the CDN and the CDN gives you the link:

```
www.myCDN.com/?id=123
```

instead of giving this url directly to your user, you could give him something like:

```
www.mysite.com/track_css.php?url=www.myCDN.com%2F%3Fid%3D123
```

or if you want to, you could save the CDN link into a Database and identify it using an id, so the url would be something like

```
www.mysite.com/track_css.php?file_id=123
```

In the track_css.php you can save any information you want (IP's, date, user-agent, etc) and after, redirect to the real file in the cdn... or maybe retreive the content and display it directly

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** Didn't see the *"without getting them to go through a PHP script first"*, =P so, never mind